# Compare a word against words in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a function `offOne(word, book)` which takes
a string called `word` and an array of strings called `book`.
It returns an array of all the `word`s in `book` of the same
length that are one letter different.

Examples:

```
offOne("cat", ["cat", "fat", "flat", "tar"]) => ["fat", "tar"]
offOne("will", ["wilt", "willow", "wail"]) => ["wilt", "wail"]
```

My function is currently:

```
function offOne(word, book) {
    var array = [];
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
        if (book.length === word.length) {
            if (word.indexOf(book[i]) !== -1) {
                count += 1;

                if (count === (book[i].length - 1)) {
                    array.push(book[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I got stuck for a while here.

Comment: Or could be an pre-interview screening question?

Comment: The question is not well stated in the sense that it is not really SO conform in my opinion. What exactly is your issue? I doubt you would get an answer delivering the algorithm to solve your task. The function definition does not make much sense to me and I have the feeling you don't understand JavaScript so well; try to start from there: length of book and length of word - why would you compare the length of a string with the length of an array?

Comment: This is one of my 50 prep questions to prepare for a course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippets are well addressed with comments. It should help you. Do Check it!

**Points to remember for your prep:**

1. Don't declare unnecessary variables. It consumes memory, which is bad.
2. Don't use unnecessary loops. Check for available language API before using loops. Like, I used [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `foreach`. These will reduce your work.
3. Always consider [`Logical operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).
4. Make the code dead simple.

Best of luck for your course!

**My way of doing it**

```js
var word = "cat";
var book = ["car", "far", "mars", "call", "bat"]

function compare(elm, word) {
  var i = 0
  elm.split('').forEach(c => { //tokenize elm of book into array
    if (word.indexOf(c) > -1) //check if charecter in present in the word
      i += 1 //if yes, increment
  })
  return i === word.length - 1 ? true : false //return true if length of i is (length of word - 1), 
}

function offOne(word, book) {
  return book.filter(elm =>
    // check, if the length of both strings are not same and
    // both strings are not same and
    // compare strings, true will be returned if the condition is satisfied in compare()
    elm.length === word.length && elm !== word && compare(elm, word)
  )
}

console.log(offOne(word, book))
```

**My advanced way of doing it**

If you see, this one doesn't have any variables declared inside the functions.

```js
var word = "cat";
var book = ["car", "far", "mars", "call", "bat"]

function compare(elm, word) {
  return elm.split('').filter(c => //tokenize elm of book into array
    word.indexOf(c) > -1 //check if charecter in present in the word, if yes, return true
  ).join('').length === word.length - 1 ? true : false //join and check the length of the array is one less than length of the word, if yes, return true
}

function offOne(word, book) {
  return book.filter(elm =>
    // check, if the length of both strings are not same and
    // both strings are not same and
    // compare strings, true will be returned if the condition is satisfied in compare()
    elm.length === word.length && elm !== word && compare(elm, word)
  )
}

console.log(offOne(word, book))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert word to array of letters, make this array unique. For each book array item do the same and calculate the number of different characters between them. If only one difference is found, return the item, repeat for each.

Comment: so i have to split the word, iterate over them, check the indexOf for book, but how do i check if only one difference is found?

Comment: You can iterate over elements of one array and increase the counter for each item that is not contained within the second one. Those are basics of programming.